# In tensorflow, how to use the placeholder's value before feeding?

Tags: python, tensorflow

New to TensorFlow,Now I need to use the value in placeholder before feeding, something like:

```
tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
Mat_items = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,10]))
Mat_users = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,10]))
item_index = tensor[:, 0]
user_index = tensor[:, 1]
rating = tensor[:, 2]
Val = Mat_items[item_index, :]-Mat_users[user_index, :]
```

while *tensor* is a placeholder with N rows 3 cols, first col and second col is the index to Mat_items and Mat_users respectively and *Mat_items* *Mat_users* are the Variables needed to be indexed.
Running it will absolutely throw an error because item_index, user_index both are *Tensor* not *numeric* before feeding.
So I wonder whether Tensorflow could realize this demand?
Any suggestion will be appreciate!:)

=========================================================================
Addition to my question:
`Val` depends on certain columns in `Tensor` just like first column and second columns. So when i create my graph, i code

```
Val = Mat_items[item_index, :]-Mat_users[user_index, :]
```

item_index and user_index are the slice of `tensor`, and both of them are type `tensor` too.It will throw error.I dont know how to realize this demand in TensorFlow.

=========================================================================
Have found a solution:

```
tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
Mat_items = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,10]))
Mat_users = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,10]))
for each in range(batch_number):
    item_ind, user_ind = tensor[each, 2], tensor[each, 1]
    rating = tensor[each, 1]
    Val = Mat_item[item_ind, 0]*Mat_user[user_ind, 0]*rating
```

Code above seems to work while building the gragh cost too much time even with a litte dataset(batch-size about 1000 and only one batch is feeded for testing), It will roughly cost 78 second to build the graph, I are not sure if it's normal?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems vague, but I guess your question is how to place values into placeholder. If you want to obtain the output from `Val`, you have to supplement `tensor` with an input, as it does not contain any values by default. `Val` also depends on `tensor` in order to compute its output. Your input has to be of the same size as `tensor`. (In this case, lets assume your input is random noise `input_tensor = numpy.random.uniform(-1, 1, size =(None, 3))` where None is a value you have to specify.

So after you begin a session, execute
`output = sess.run(Val, feed_dict = {tensor: input_tensor})`
and `output` will be your result

Comment: yes, *Val* depends on *tensor*.Specifically, *Val* depends on the value in certain columns of *tensor*, as the value in those columns is the index of the *Val*. But if i create my graph like `Val = Mat_items[item_index, :]-Mat_users[user_index, :]` will throw error. Will my question be more clear?